# D3: Overflow in SVG group element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, overflow, legend

I have the following SVG:

[image]

The legend block on the right top (highlighted by the red rectangle) is a group element containing legends for the line charts on the left.

The problem I am facing is that the number of these legends are dynamic and are added one below the other. The SVG has a fixed height (as of now) in pixels. So, my worry is that after a certain point these legends will overflow the enclosing SVG element.

Is there a way of adding a vertical scrollbar to the legend group element so that any number of legends can be incorporated? Or should I, in some way make the SVG height dynamic according to the number of legends?

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: You could put the legend into a `foreignObject` with HTML and add the scrollbars there. I'm not aware of native options to add scrollsbars in a particular SVG.

Comment: thanks, thats a good option.